# How do I rename a key with PyYAML

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have loaded a YAML file (template) that I want to modify (keys and some values).

e.g.

```
key_to_rename:
  a: "1"
  b: "2"
  c: "3"
```

How do I find & rename a key with PyYAML?

```
  my_dict = yaml.load(stream)

  for key, value in my_dict.iteritems():
     if (key == "key_to_rename"):
       print key
       key = "new_name"
       print key

  print yaml.dump(my_dict)
```

but that's still not persisting the change

Comment: I have loaded the YAML indeed, but I can't find out how to rename the key. The input comes from a file, so I could replace the string in the file, but I figured it would be more elegant if I could do that on the yaml dict. (Stefano, I hope you are not the -1)

Comment: How helpful it is to close a question?? Seriously guys!!? Give me hint at least?

Comment: `my_dict["new_name"] = value` then `my_dict.pop(key, None)`

Comment: Got it! Thanks mate. Note that I am both new to python and pyyaml (just started today). It is appreciated that someone actually tried to help instead of trying to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kyllopardiun

```
  stream = open("./tiny.yml", 'r')
  my_dict = yaml.load(stream)

  # First make a copy with a new name
  my_dict["new_name"] = qb_dict['key_to_rename'] 

  # Then remove the old key
  my_dict.pop("key_to_rename", None)
```